# Unable to import Room database for use in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I am working on developing an Android app through android studio and I am trying to implement a Room database. I was using https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room for instructions as well as https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942, however I was unable to properly import it in. Trying `import androidx.room.*;` returns `cannot resolve symbol 'room'`. I was unable to find a solution to this issue.

I have tried:

- Using `https://maven.google.com` as a repository
- Using different versions of room
- Using `api` instead of `implementation`

Project Gradle File:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

App Gradle File:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
}
```

Edit:
I have also tried this without success, as well as using room_version as 1.0.0

```
def room_version = "2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Edit: While gradle syncing, I found that it got stuck on `Download room-runtime-2.2.6.pom...` for 10-15 minutes, and once it completed it showed the warnings:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Clicking show details did not direct it anywhere

Comment: try resync with gradle files

Comment: I resynced the gradle files each time I changed them to no effect

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `androidx` dependencies. you already using using `androidx` artifact so you have to use same for `Room`. Also its mentioned in docs.

```
def room_version = "2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my gradle files sync very slowly for some reason. I tried using these dependencies but they still do not work.

Comment: @a_local_nobody those dependencies were from medium.com, it was the second source I tried after the google page ones which did not work when I tried them

Comment: I have a similar case, it worked before but, all of a sudden, RoomDBs dependencies don't work anymore. I did change nothing and they just broke the next day... I just don't get it. I even tried resyncing gradle files, changing RoomDBs version trying to fit it, but nothing...